# Laravel temporary variable is being updated without interaction

Tags: php, laravel

I can't figure out what's being done, I have two simple variables:

```
$item = Clients::findOrFail($id);
$itemTemporary = $item;
```

Now, the variable `$itemTemporary` is supposed to hold the data of `$item` and if I have any interaction in the variable `$item` this `$itemTemporary` has nothing to do with it, right?

```
$item = Clients::findOrFail($id);
$itemTemporary = $item;

print_r($itemTemporary->status); // Returns TRUE

$item->status = FALSE;
$item->save();

print_r($itemTemporary->status); // Returns FALSE
```

How d'hell is the `$itemTemporary->status` being changed?

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump( $item );`. More than likely it is an object so pointers/references are in full effect and not copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$itemTemporary` is not a copy of the `$item` object, but of the object identifier. (See [Objects and References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).) It refers to the same object. If you need to hold the data of `$item` temporarily while changing it, you need to use a different method such as cloning the object or converting it to an array.

---

Actually, I thought Laravel might have a method for this, so looked it up and apparently it does:

```
$itemTemporary = $item->replicate();
```

Comment: Please be sure to mention the [pitfalls of default cloning](https://dcsg.me/articles/dont-clone-your-php-objects-deepcopy-them/) behavior because any properties of the class which hold an object will result in the same reference in the cloned object.

Answer (score 0):

`$itemTemporary` will [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) the `$item` object which is why you are seeing this behavior.

You can [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the object like so:

```
$itemTemporary = clone $item;
```